# btrbk not taking hourly snapshots

Tags: cron, snapshot, btrfs

I have installed btrbk and I would like hourly snapshots to be taken. However, only daily snapshots are done. I wonder what goes wrong.

Pleas help me out.

Environment: OS: Ubuntu 23.04 64bit / Linux 6.2.0-26-generic
btrbk version: 0.32.5

```
$ cat /etc/btrbk/btrbk.conf
transaction_log            /var/log/btrbk.log
timestamp_format           long

snapshot_dir               _btrbk_snapshots
snapshot_create            always
incremental                yes
preserve_hour_of_day       0
preserve_day_of_week       sunday
snapshot_preserve_min      48h
snapshot_preserve          48h 7d 10w
target_preserve            24h 7d 10w
lockfile                   /var/lock/btrbk.lock

volume /mnt/btrbk_pool
  snapshot_dir _btrbk_snapshots

  subvolume /
  subvolume docker
  subvolume docker/nextcloud/data
    snapshot_name nextcloud_data
```

```
$ cat /etc/cron.hourly/btrbk 
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/btrbk -q run
```

And the log: https://pastebin.com/ZWAE8DDB (I find it too long to be posted as plain text. Sorry.)

Comment: try to use roots crontab for a crossover test. `crontab -e -u root` and insert `@hourly <your command here>` and see if it's working native text logs should be posted directly instead

Answer (score 0):

I have realized the problem is the incorrect permissions of the /etc/cron.hourly/btrbk file. It lacks executable permission for the owner (root). It works fine with the permissions fixed.